# Wikipedia UX - Paginated content appealing?

Tags: feedback

I would like to get feedbacks on the UI of the service. It provides 48000 public domain books and Wikipedia. The service called "Wikipedia for Readers" let the readers focus on one article, providing book reading experience while clicking other article links will bring the content to the sidebar.

[image: Star Wars article with sidebar content]

It works for me but not sure if it appeals to anyone else. To get to the example article above, click http://buk.io/@en/Star%20Wars

Also, quoting part of an article is possible with the service. Click the "share" icon on the top navigation and select the text you want to share, then you will have adjusted URL that you can put into facebook/Gplus posting.

Here is a partial text example. If you click the quote, it will show the page that contains the text and highlight it.

[Three years later, Luke travels to find the Jedi Master Yoda, now living in exile on the swamp-infested world of Dagobah, to begin his Jedi training.](http://buk.io/@en/Star%20Wars/743:0:0~743:4:29?version=666132214)

My questions:

1. Does the UX of the site work any good for you or it only complicates your viewing of the content?
2. Additional feature like sharing part of the article may be useful to you?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing part of an article would be nice if done right. I think typically people can only share a whole article though so it might seem a little counterintuitive - maybe it's worth just going for sharing the whole article to begin with and then adding the other functionality over time?

Also the UI isn't too problematic though I'd be careful with the text wrapping around the images as in the example above it's a bit choppy around the death star image and that's not exactly conducive to easy reading (which I think is one of the main ideas of your platform).

It's also worth explaining to people on their first visit to the platform that this split view exists otherwise they'll like click 'open in new tab' on links out of habit and not realise the functionality is there (maybe you already do this, just thought I'd mention it in case).

It could also be helpful to allow users to make the secondary panel become the primary viewing area if they find themselves more interested in the side channel they are pursuing. I often read wikipedia, follow a link and then find that article more interesting and read that in full without returning to finish the earlier section in full.